# Error 403: The supplied authentication is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: python, post, request, http-status-code-403

I want to send a POST request to the following URL and get the result.

```
https://www.snapptrip.com/flights/THR-tehran/KIH-kish-island?roundTrip=false&adultCount=1&childCount=0&inLapCount=0&date=2022-07-01&cabinType=E
```

To do this I have copied all headers and cookies from browser and set them like as follows:

```
import json

import requests
        header = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-length': '147',
    'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'cookie': 'route=1656317791.775.282.960981; _gcl_au=1.1.2046258357.1656317792; analytics_campaign={%22source%22:%22google%22%2C%22medium%22:%22organic%22}; analytics_token=42b8404c-38bc-f45a-5da5-4b0a9d8d64d3; _yngt_iframe=1; _yngt=7cf79f92-2a8e5-5857f-fc332-20702cb6182a1; _gid=GA1.2.1347682050.1656317794; _hjSessionUser_1680486=eyJpZCI6IjI4YzJkNDgxLWQ5ZmMtNTE0ZC04ODZmLWY0YmU4YWUzZTY0MyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTYzMTgwMjQwOTgsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; CustomerKey=c6daab9d-76a3-318b-9dc4-a998b9aa3d77; _clck=11btp2n|1|f2q|0; analytics_session_token=6fd59170-a4ac-3fe4-48c2-6672506db682; yektanet_session_last_activity=6/29/2022; _6193bae56a6d2e30f5357d82=true; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjSession_1680486=eyJpZCI6IjhlNGU0MWQ4LThmM2QtNGQyNy05YjY2LTRmMDViYTQzYjM3ZCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTY0NzgwOTM2NTUsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; crisp-client%2Fsession%2Fdb7f3f50-c4be-4ec3-85f9-24c3cff11750=session_8eb3f713-17e8-4046-ad90-ecec16421bed; marketingData={"utm_medium":"","utm_campaign":"","utm_source":"","utm_content":"","utm_term":"","referrer":"https://www.snapptrip.com/flights/THR-tehran/MHD-mashhad?date=2022-08-22&returnDate=&roundTrip=false&adultCount=1&childCount=0&inLapCount=0&cabinType=E"}; flightMarketingData={"utm_medium":"","utm_campaign":"","utm_source":"","utm_content":"","utm_term":"","referrer":"https://www.snapptrip.com/flights/THR-tehran/MHD-mashhad?date=2022-08-22&returnDate=&roundTrip=false&adultCount=1&childCount=0&inLapCount=0&cabinType=E"}; destinationCity=%D9%85%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%AF; _gat_UA-107687430-1=1; _ga_DKJN1PETDV=GS1.1.1656478091.3.1.1656480799.49; _ga=GA1.2.312049892.1656317793; _clsk=1bf2oby|1656480801280|29|1|h.clarity.ms/collect',
    'origin': 'https://www.snapptrip.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': ' https://www.snapptrip.com/flights/THR-tehran/MHD-mashhad?roundTrip=false&adultCount=1&childCount=0&inLapCount=0&date=2022-06-30&cabinType=E',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Linux',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    'x-access-token': '26a53f65-4702-4f99-a5d3-ed03e03ca6e6',
    'x-customer-key': 'c6daab9d-76a3-318b-9dc4-a998b9aa3d77',
    'x-request-id': 'Bearer db312b1422dc4ec4f657de5909612a238af4592d5c25828cccb5bb319090fbf8.e7cf77e7-1d36-489d-9df3-ada35364681e',
    'x-session-id': '3cfbed40-7932-46ee-9513-f342813be7c3',
    'x-user-id': '71d3efa6-6d61-4d3d-89b2-16f1e1a201a1',
}
data = {"origin": "THR", "destination": "MHD", "roundTrip": false,
        "passengers": {"adults": 1, "children": 0, "infants": 0}, "cabinType": "E", "departDate": "2022-06-30"}

url = 'https://www.snapptrip.com/flights/THR-tehran/KIH-kish-island?roundTrip=false&adultCount=1&childCount=0&inLapCount=0&date=2022-07-01&cabinType=E'
res = requests.post(url=url, json=json.dumps(data), headers=header)
```

The header and cookie images in the browser are as follows:
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

After all, it throws following error:

```
403: The supplied authentication is not authorized to access this resource
```

Comment: because when I brows that site with a browser(like chrome) it has used POST. You can see that in the image that I posted.

Comment: @AlbertWinestein No any suggestions?